# How to construct a string containing the keys of a map in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, terraform

I have a bunch of files that are published to an S3 bucket managed using the terraform script below. To make file tracking easy, I used a combination of `for_each` when declaring an aws_s3_object and `fileset()` to grab the list of files from my local volume.

I want to create an SSM Parameter that contains a common separated string of the list of files that I have published to S3 using the aws_s3_object (ie: "scripts/app/script1.py, scripts/app/script2.py, scripts/app/script3.py")

My approach to this problem is to use a combination of `locals` block and `for` statement to iterate over each key of `aws_s3_object.app_files` map
and construct the string, but I can't figure out how to write this `for` statement as the examples from [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) seem to suggest that the results of the `for` statement will result in a list or object and not a string.

Is it even possible to do this? And if so, how can this be achieved?

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "app_files" {
  for_each  = fileset("scripts/", "**.py")

  bucket = "myBucket"
  key = "dev/app/${each.value}"
  server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"
  bucket_key_enabled = true

  source = "scripts/${each.value}"
  source_hash = filemd5("scripts/${each.value}")

  tags = {
    Name = each.value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use [join](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/join):

```
locals {
  joined_keys = join(",", keys(aws_s3_object.app_files)) 
}
```

Sometimes, `json` string may be more useful:

```
locals {
  joined_keys_json = jsonencode(keys(aws_s3_object.app_files)) 
}
```